# JSF editable textbox is escaping characters on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a form that has a `inputTextarea` to input comments. I also have a `validator` that checks for invalid code such as `< > &` and will display an error message if one of those characters is input.

The issue is that if I enter, for instance, `<` into the `inputTextarea` and hit submit, the form is refreshed and I am given an error message that says that is an invalid text.

That works fine. When the page refreshes though the `<` character that I entered is changed to `&lt;`. How can I this from happening when the page refreshes?

Here is the section of the code that has the `inputTextarea`:

```
<div class="validationMessage" <h:message id="textError" for="test" styleClass="ValidationError"/> </div>
<h:inputTextarea cols="50" rows="5" id="test" value="#{createModel.txt} validator="#{validator.txt}"></h:inputTextarea>
```

The validation works just fine. The issue is that the invalid text `<` gets changed to `&lt;` on form page refresh. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Something else not visible in information provided so far is doing that.

Comment: So, typically this issue wouldn't occur with an inputTextarea and you are suggesting that there is some other outside influence that is causing this issue?

Comment: Simply put: when I create a blank JSF project with most minimal configuration and most recent versions, and create a test page based on solely the relevant information provided so far, then it works just fine for me. I suggest you to do the same and then compare to existing code (or just create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).